# Share the same Redux store between two apps causing memory leak

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I have got three apps : Background, MainApp and Settings.

I have created the store in the background and I am accessing it in MainApp and Settings. Everything works well but whenever I close one of my app, I get a "detached window" (a memory leak) according to Chrome Dev tools.

MainApp.tsx

```
const backgroundStore = getBackgroundWindowHTMLObject().myStore

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement)
root.render(
        <Provider store={backgroundStore}>
            <MainApp/>
        </Provider>
);
```

SettingsApp.tsx

```
const backgroundStore = getBackgroundWindowHTMLObject().myStore

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement)
root.render(
        <Provider store={backgroundStore}>
            <SettingsApp/>
        </Provider>
);
```

How can I unset the reference to the store in `<Provider store={backgroundStore}>` before closing my settings window?